# Javascript - .innerHTML - Displaying Text format Correctly

Tags: javascript, html

Rather New to javascript and hoping that I've come to the right place.

Currently I am trying to make a button that will place specific formatted text in a text box, however I am unsure on how to make the text keep its format.

I would like to be able to include elements like p /p and b /b in the text.

Example how I'd like to see it: 
Customer is having problems, 
 please proceed to the location and repair the service

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = "Customer is having problems, please proceed to the location and repair the service ";
  var oTextbox1 = document.getElementById("textbox"); 
oTextbox1.focus(); 
oTextbox1.select(); 
document.execCommand('copy')
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[If you use innerHTML then html gets rendered, if you use innerText then it is left unrendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-and-innerhtml-in-javascript)

[Considering input can't contain HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823835/html-in-the-input-field-value) You might want to look into [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable). [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360863/why-would-one-choose-an-editable-div-over-an-input-or-textarea)

```js
document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML = "<b>Bolded?</b>";
document.getElementById("test2").innerText = "<b>Bolded?</b>";
```

```html
<div id="test1" contenteditable></div>
<div id="test2" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt appear to work for me, my button is placing directly into a text box not an open div. could that be the problem?

Comment: document.getElementById("textbox").innerHTML = "Customer is having problems,<BR/> please proceed to the location and repair the service ";  Use html in that string, you can't.

Comment: [You can't put HTML in the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823835/html-in-the-input-field-value)

Comment: @PatrickJohnston Updated my example with contenteditable. The input itself can't have HTML but you can make something (which can have html) editable!